# CArray and memory pre-allocation

Tags: c++, mfc, dynamic-arrays

I'm working with the code in a MFC project that uses CArray class to work with dynamic arrays. It works as such:

```
CArray<CUSTOM_STRUCT> arr;
while(some_criteria)
{
    CUSTOM_STRUCT cs;
    add.add(cs);
}
```

This approach works, but becomes really slow with a large number of additions to dynamic array. So I was curious, is there a way to preallocate memory in CArray before I begin calling the add() method?

There's one caveat though. I can only estimate approximately the resulting number of elements in the array before I go into my while() loop.

PS. I cannot use any other arrays than CArray.

PS2. Due to complexity of this prokect, I would prefer to keep additions to the array via the add() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, really consider swapping out for a `std::vector`.  It is surprisingly easy.

This is an attempt to make `CArray` follow a `std::vector`-like growth policy, instead of by 1 each time:

```
CArray<CUSTOM_STRUCT> arr;
while(some_criteria) {
  CUSTOM_STRUCT cs;
  arr.SetSize( arr.GetSize(), 1 + arr.GetSize()/2 );
  arr.add(cs);
}
```

When I run into this problem, I replace the `CArray` with a `std::vector`, so I haven't tested the above.  Reading the docs, it should work.  Test it and see if you get a massive performance increase (it should go from O(n^2) down to O(n) amortized)).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just from curiosity, why is that `std::vector` is so much better than `CArray`? PS. I'm still on Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @c00000fd As an example, if you did the above operation with `std::vector` it would just work, and you wouldn't have a performance problem.  I am no `CArray` expert, I just know enough to be able to remove it from a code base when I need to (usually for maintenance (we find `std::vector` easier to work with) or performance reasons).

Comment: Is it still available for older compilers/IDEs, i.e. VS 2008?

Comment: @c00000fd `#include <vector>`.  It is worth learning but your first use of it should not be replacing CArray with it, I will admit.  (it is not a drop-in replacement).

Comment: Hey, one last question. Do you know if MFC's `CString` is also affected by the same memory allocation issue?

Comment: @c00000fd no, I do not know.  A quick google says that it has a [linear growth policy](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/cstring-concatenation-advice-pls/551364).  [Another link talks about exponential to 1k, then linear](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/cstring-addition-of-large-strings/555069), but that is also a decade old.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CArray::SetSize()` method to preallocate the memory.

Please note if the memory is preallocated you should use `CArray::operator[]` instead of `CArray::Add` method.